# Django queries for ManyToManyFields

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm trying to make a clone of a dating app and attempting to retrieve the profiles which meet my user's condition. I've made a Profile model which is many to many with itself and a Match models which joins the 'liker' and 'likee' and adds additional fields. I'm trying to retrieve all the profiles I haven't swiped on yet. I've been able to do this with multiple database calls but want to know if there's a way of doing it with a single/fewer queries.

my models look like this

```
class Profile(models.Model):

  class MatchGenderChoices(models.TextChoices):
    FEMALE = 'FEMALE'
    MALE = 'MALE'
    ALL = 'ALL'

  class GenderChoices(models.TextChoices):
      FEMALE = 'FEMALE'
      MALE = 'MALE'
      NONBINARY = 'NONBINARY'
  display_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
  age = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
  gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices = GenderChoices.choices, null = True, blank = False)
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  liked_profiles = models.ManyToManyField('self', through= 'Match')
  match_distance = models.IntegerField(default = 30)
  match_age_max = models.IntegerField(default = 99)
  match_age_min = models.IntegerField(default = 18)
  match_gender =  models.CharField(max_length=10, choices = MatchGenderChoices.choices, null = True, blank = False)

  city = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
  latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6, null = True)
  longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6, null = True)
  age = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False,validators=[MinValueValidator(MIN_AGE), MaxValueValidator(MAX_AGE)])
  bio = models.TextField(max_length=5000, default = "Add a bio", null = True)
  profile_picture_url = models.ImageField(default = os.path.join( "media", "images","default_profile_picture.jpg"), blank = True, upload_to = "images/")



@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()


class Match(models.Model):
  liker = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "liker")
  likee = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "likee", null = True)
  match = models.BooleanField(default= False)
  date_liked= models.DateField(auto_now=True)
  date_confirmed =models.DateField(null= True, blank = True)
  class Meta:
    unique_together = [['liker', 'likee']]
```

and the way I'm implementing getting this 'deck' of profiles is as so

```
def get_profiles(profile):
  # returns list of profiles where the age and genders match the user's choices
  exclude_id_list = [profile.id]
  exclude_id_list.extend(list(Match.objects.filter(liker_id =profile.id).values_list('likee_id', flat=True)))
  exclude_id_list.extend( list(Match.objects.filter(Q(likee_id=profile.id) & ~Q(date_confirmed__isnull=True) ).values_list('liker_id', flat=True)))
  if profile.match_gender == 'ALL':
    matches = Profile.objects.exclude(id__in = exclude_id_list).filter(Q(age__lte=profile.match_age_max) & Q(age__gte=profile.match_age_min))
  else:
    matches = Profile.objects.exclude(id__in = exclude_id_list).filter(Q(age__lte=profile.match_age_max) & Q(age__gte=profile.match_age_min) & Q(gender=profile.match_gender))
```

I'm fairly certain I'm doing something completely wrong here but I'm pretty lost on where to start with this

Answer (score 0):

this example how you can deal with many to many:

```
class A(models.Model):
      name= models.CharField(...)

class B(models.Model):
      a= models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

you can access data in this way:

```
model_b_object.a.all()
```

or

```
A.objects.filter(b=model_b_object)
```